# Can regex read user specified strings?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Whether using regex we can get the content between two user specified strings?
I am using python. So far I found :

```
re.findall ( r'string1(.*?)string2', text, re.DOTALL)
```

But can these strings be read as user input and not as fixed one's. Is this possible?
Any suggestions is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not? But you will have to check whether they are correct regex patterns before applying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string concatenation to build the search string/regex:

```
string1 = "foo"
string2 = "bar"

re.findall(r'{}(.*?){}'.format(string1, string2), text, re.DOTALL)
```

**Edit**: I took inspiration from @Kasramvd's answer since `string.format` is cleaner and enables you to use the `r` decoration for regex escaping. You may or may not want to `re.escape` the strings depending on the use case.

Comment: That looks simple :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the strings using `raw_input()` and (if you want to add none-regex string) escape the string using `re.escape()` in order to escape the regex notations (which may exist in your string)

```
import re
string1 = re.escape(raw_input("enter first string: "))
string2 = re.escape(raw_input("enter second string: "))

re.findall(r"{}(.*?){}".format(string1, string2), text, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Why escape if a user is supposed to type a *regular expression pattern* into the input field?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP has said *user specified strings* and not regex, but the other side is that he means a regex, let me update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I always use:

```
import re
string1=raw_input()
string2=raw_input()
check=re.compile(r'%s(.*)%s'%(string1,string2),re.DOTALL)
check.findall()
```

Hope this helps you out. Thanks!